# Inject current class property into new class's constructor

Tags: ruby, class

I am trying to create a class which initializes a WEBrick server which contains a WEBrick servlet which returns some default HTML string if no request path is given.

The main issue is I'd be injecting an instance variable of the current class into the constructor of a new class, and this is something I don't really know how to do.

```
class MyServer
  def initialize(defaultHTML)
    @defaultHtml = defaultHTML
    @server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
      :Port => 12357,
      :DocumentRoot = Dir.pwd
    )
    defaultGetHandler = Class.new(WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet) do
      def do_GET(request,response)
        if request.path.to_s == "/"
          response.body = #SOMEHOW get @defaultHTML here...?
        end
      end
    end
    @server.mount "/", defaultGetHandler
  end
end
```

I expect this is possible. I have tried using global variables already and these do work alright, however it's not exactly ideal.

Comment: Can't you use constants name spaced in the class?

Comment: Isn't the block supposed to be the `do_GET` method`?

Comment: @sawa I had also thought the same, but figured that it was really no better than using a global variable, given that multiple instances of this class may be running/initialising at one time (given my particular use case). I probably should have made port a constructor variable in the example.

Comment: If each instance needs to have different values, then why do you want those to be shared within the class? That is contradictory.

Comment: @KimmoLehto indeed! Apologies, I didn't paste this code directly. This has now been changed.

Comment: @sawa I think you're missing the point. The whole point of the class is such that: `MyClass.new("<html>hello</html>",12357)` and `MyClass.new("<html>world</html>",12358)` will produce 2 separate running servers, each with different default pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: @engineersmnky 's answer is a lot better for your specific usecase. This answer could be of interest to someone looking for a solution to similar, but not `WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet` related problem.

You could define a class instance variable accessor and pass in the `defaultHtml` after dynamically creating the class, like so:

```
class MyServer
  def initialize(defaultHTML)
    @defaultHtml = defaultHTML
    @server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
      :Port => 12357,
      :DocumentRoot = Dir.pwd
    )
    defaultGetHandler = Class.new(WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet) do
      class << self
        attr_accessor :defaultHtml  # class level attr_accessor
      end

      def do_GET(request,response)
        if request.path.to_s == "/"
          # reference to class level instance variable:
          response.body = self.class.defaultHtml 
        end
      end
    end

    defaultGetHandler.defaultHtml = @defaultHtml

    @server.mount "/", defaultGetHandler
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears `WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet` already offers an appropriate interface for this ([Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.4/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServlet/AbstractServlet.html#method-c-get_instance)) e.g.

```
 class DefaultGetHandler < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
   def initialize(server,default_html)
     super(server)
     @default_html = default_html
   end 
   def do_GET(request,response)
     if request.path.to_s == "/"
      response.body = @default_html
     end
   end
 end
```

Then `MyServer` becomes

```
class MyServer
  def initialize(default_html)
    @server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
      :Port => 12357,
      :DocumentRoot = Dir.pwd
    )

    @server.mount "/", DefaultGetHandler, default_html
  end
end
```

This will allow you to avoid all the anonymous class definitions you are creating right now and provide you with a cleaner implementation of your custom class. You could name space `DefaultGetHandler` inside `MyServer` if you'd like to maintain the encapsulation you currently have